# Keeping Textview content on 1 line and prevent wrapping

Tags: android, textview, widget

I would like to have a text displayed on an Android widget (remote views) not wrap over its text to the next line, if the text is longer than the `Textview`'s width. Instead of that, I would like to have the Textview cut any extra text. I have tried many things without success.

Here is the XML code for the `TextView`:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtInformation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:maxWidth="220dp"
        android:lines="1"
        android:text="Long text long text long text long text"
        android:textSize="13sp" />
```

Comment: Please, post your code or `xml` file with the `TextView` in question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your layout XML, use `android:maxLines="1"` or `android:singleLine="true"`

Comment: I have done that, still the same problem. When the text displayed is longer that the length of the TextView, it wraps to the next line

Comment: I have assigned a style to the textview and added the following attributes and it works fine now: lines=1, maxLines=1, inputType=text, singleLine=true. SingleLine has been deprecated and replaced with inputType so removing singleLine should also work.

Comment: As of now, `lines=1` should work by itself, using Android Studio 3.2

Comment: I've tried `maxLines=1` and `lines=1`, and even `scrollHorizontally=true` in all combinations and the issue still occurs with a `<MultiAutoCompleteTextView>`. `inputType=text` *must* be set for this to work.